# Apache RewriteRule in virtual-host(Apache)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the following URL:

**http://www.example.com/Bengaluru/Cantonment**

to

**http://www.example.com/Bengaluru/Cantonment-HRBR/6238393**

I wrote this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  `^(.*)/Cantonment  $1/Cantonment-HRBR/6238393 [R,L]`
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Whats this `\`` before the pattern and after the flags `\``?

Comment: nothing, I am using without `

Comment: Then remove it. Why you have used them?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Bengaluru/Cantonment/(.*)$ /Bengaluru/Cantonment-HRBR/6238393/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Its redirecting home page ie www.example.com, but want to redirect to http://www.example.com/Bengaluru/Cantonment-HRBR/6238393

Comment: Same result, its redirecting home page www.example.com

Comment: use [R,NC,L], NC means "case insensitive"

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh (or try it in another)? The above is working for me.

Comment: Thanks its working, I have add some more re directives like RewriteRule  ^Bengaluru/JC/(.*)$  /Bengaluru/JCRoad-LalbaghRoad/6238354/$1 [R,NC,L], its working for Cantonment not for others following for some re directives  RewriteRule  ^Bengaluru/WOC/(.*)$ /Bengaluru/WOCRoad-Yeshwanthpur/6147824/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^Bengaluru/Mekhri/(.*)$ /Bengaluru/MekhriCircle-Hebbal/6238319/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^Bengaluru/KR/(.*)$ /Bengaluru/KRPuram-Marathahalli-ORR/6152062/$1 [R,NC,L]

Comment: Remove the `,L` from all but the last `RewriteRule` because `L` tells it to stop applying rules after that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Cantonment /$1/Cantonment-HRBR/6238393 [R=302,NC,L]
```